# How to merge on multiple keys and add remaming info on conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a simple Dataframe that i am performing a merge it has three labels, Id, year and a value, and I have another Df that has the same Id a different year and some names for a simple example df1 looks like this :

```
Id Value Year
1   10   2010
6   11   2020
3   12   2019
4   15   2018
2   17   2017
```

and df2 looks like this:

```
    Id names Year
    1   bs   2017
    2   fs   2017
    6   td   2020
    4   dh   2018
    3   sv   2019
```

So I'm merging on using:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['Id', 'Year'],right_on=['Id', 'Year'],how='left')
```

The answer I want to get is this but I don't know how to do it:

```
Id Value Year names
1   10   2010  bs
6   11   2020  td
3   12   2019  sv 
4   15   2018  dh
5   17   2017  fs
```

So the idea is that the data below 2017 can be assigned from the data of 2017 the dataframe I have is much longer.

Comment: df2 has bs and fs for 2017. So, how would you know which one has to match for the last row in the df1

Comment: Based on the id because the match i'm doing based on year and id, So if the year is below 2017 add the data from 2017 for that id

Comment: Joining on Id alone gives you the required result here. @SeaBean's answer below does the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make temporary column where you use some constant for years <=2017 and merge on `Id` and this column:

```
df1["tmp"] = np.where(df1["Year"] <= 2017, 1, df1["Year"])
df2["tmp"] = np.where(df2["Year"] <= 2017, 1, df2["Year"])

df3 = pd.merge(
    df1, df2, left_on=["Id", "tmp"], right_on=["Id", "tmp"], how="left"
)

print(
    df3[["Id", "Value", "Year_x", "names"]].rename(columns={"Year_x": "Year"})
)
```

Prints:

```
   Id  Value  Year names
0   1     10  2010    bs
1   6     11  2020    td
2   3     12  2019    sv
3   4     15  2018    dh
4   2     17  2017    fs
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are going to attach the `names` column of `df2` to `df1` with matching `Id`, we can make the 2 dataframes with same index on `Id` and join them after dropping the `Year` column of df2.

We can use `.join()` with `.set_index()` as follows:

```
(df1.set_index('Id')
    .join(
          df2.set_index('Id')
             .drop(columns='Year')
         )
).reset_index()


# Result


   Id  Value  Year names
0   1     10  2010    bs
1   6     11  2020    td
2   3     12  2019    sv
3   4     15  2018    dh
4   2     17  2017    fs
```